# Is there a Spring annotation to simplify throwing an error if the id field is in the request body

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

From what I have read about REST:

- The id of a resource should be a path variable, rather than in the request body
- If there is an id in the request body, it is invalid input and should return 400

Does Spring Annotations provide a simple way to add this check to what is validated with `@Valid`?

I can certainly code this myself. I just want to use as many Spring Annotation shortcuts as are available. I am looking for some kind of annotation that I can put on the Model (or elsewhere, I guess) that throws an error if a field is present in the `@RequestBody` object, but does not prevent a model from being persisted with a value in that field.

Comment: you should configured your controller's `@RequestMapping` as having a path variable inside and method having a `@PathVariable` as a parameter. Then you don't need to care if id is present in the request body or not. If it is absent from path, your method will not get invoked. If it is present, then you don't care about request body.

Comment: I currently do have that setup. It ignores the id field in the body and uses the path variable instead. However, my understanding of REST suggests that it should not be ignored, that it should be treated as an error instead

Comment: Why this should be error? I mean, REST is not some sort of RFC standard :)

Comment: There are other threads debating that subject, the question that this thread raises is about how to implement.